# How to Delete Whitespace Backwards in XCode

Tags: xcode

I would like to use Xcode editor instead of others for Swift typing but I am missing basic functionality of deleting whitespace backward.

Normally in the world of code editors, you just press Option + Backspace or something similar and that is it. It deletes whitespace just until next character starts,
eating new line in the way as everyone needs.

But Xcode is doing some weird unusable stuff and is deleting not just whitespace and new line,
but also part of text on previous line until it considers some character start of word--basically making it unusable.

Comment: something certainly seems to have deleted a whole bunch of letters in your question....

Comment: Not really, I edited it so you can read it easier haha

Comment: I will try to ask on stackoverflow where more people know workarounds for this, issue is that its not correct question for that site.

Comment: I use Command-Delete to delete all text to the left of the cursor, and then press Delete again to place the cursor at the end of the previous line.